# Ember.js: Ensure linkTo helper retains active class on a nested route

Tags: ember.js

Take the following route:

```
@resource 'settings', path: '/settings', ->
  @route 'alerts'
```

and the following link:

```
{{#linkTo settings.index}}Settings{{/linkTo}}
```

Is there a specific way in Ember to ensure that the above link is `.active` as long as I am at a `settings.*` route?

Comment: I tend to do computed property for this, but I'm curious to see other (proper) implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that if you instead use:

```
{{#linkTo "settings"}}Settings{{/linkTo}}
```

it will stay active as long as you are within the `settings.*` route. The above link will route to `settings.index` anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed it working once I updated to 1.0, so I'm wondering if that was fixed in one of the releases after I posted this question.